# TouchableOpacity not working inside Animated.View

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I am trying to translate a ball from one position (x1,y1) to another (x2,y2).
This translation is supposed to take place after clicking the ball.

I am using Animated.View which gets the current position of ball from a state variable. Inside this Animated.View I am wrapping the children using Touchable Opacity. I also looked around in internet and as per my understanding, this problem is related to absolute position of ball (initial and final position of ball is passed as a prop from parent)

```
<Animated.View style={this.state.position.getLayout()}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>console.log('clicked')}>
        <View>
            {this.props.children}
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

I am unable to understand why onPress is not getting triggered and also want to know the solution to this problem. Thanks

Comment: If i take touchable opacity outside of Animated.View, onPress starts to respond but layout gets disturbed

Comment: Please add how the return values of this.state.position.getLayout look like

Comment: `{left: AnimatedValue, top: AnimatedValue}
left: AnimatedValue
_animation: null
_children: []
_listeners: {}
_offset: 0
_startingValue: 70
_tracking: null
_value: 70
__proto__: AnimatedWithChildren
top: AnimatedValue
_animation: null
_children: []
_listeners: {}
_offset: 0
_startingValue: 797.7142857142857
_tracking: null
_value: 400
__proto__: AnimatedWithChildren
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 4):

Use TouchableOpacity from 'react-native-gesture-handler' instead of from 'react-native'.

import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Follow this post Cannot click TouchableOpacity in animated.view using React native